# OnlineCalculator with Sqrt, COS,SIN,log, and back button

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on an Online Calculator program and I'm having difficulty getting my buttons to work. I have no idea why this isn't working seeing as I've already done all of the logic and everything. I just need the dang buttons to work. I'm retrieving my buttons and putting them into 2 arrays like this:

```
var operatorEl = document.getElementsByClassName('operator');
var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addme');
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       // Addings operators
       var operatorEl = document.getElementsByClassName('operator');
       // Adding btnElements
       var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addme');
       //var to store user input and button input
       var inputVal = '';
       var buttonVal = '';

       function clearContent(){
           document.getElementById('display').textContent = '';
       }
       operatorEl[0].onclick = clearContent;

       function backBtn() {
           var dvLength = buttonVal.length;
           buttonVal.substring(0,dvLength);
           document.getElementById('display').textContent = buttonVal;
       }
       operatorEl[1].onclick = backBtn;

       function calcCos(){
           inputVal = document.getElementById('display').value;
           var newVal = Math.cos(inputVal);
           document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = newVal;
       }
       operatorEl[2].onclick = calcCos;

       function calcSin() {
           inputVal = document.getElementById('display').value;
           var newVal = Math.sin(inputVal);
           document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = newVal;
       }
       operatorEl[3].onclick = calcSin;

       function calcSqrt(){
           inputVal = document.getElementById('display').value;
           if(inputVal < 0){
               document.getElementById('error-msg').textContent = 'Cannot calculate the square root of a negative number.';
               document.getElementById('display').textContent = '';
           }

           var newVal = Math.sqrt(inputVal);
           document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = newVal;
       }    
       operatorEl[4].onclick = calcSqrt;

       function calcLog(){
           inputVal = document.getElementById('display').value;
           if(inputVal < 1){
               document.getElementById('error-msg').textContent = 'Cannot calculate the log of a non-positive number.';
               document.getElementById('display').textContent = '';
           }

           var newVal = Math.log(inputVal);
           document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = newVal;
       }
       operatorEl[5].onclick = calcLog;

       //When clicked the button's value will be added to the buttonVal and put into display
       for(var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++){
           if(btnElements[i].onclick){
               buttonVal += btnElements[i].value;
               document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = buttonVal;
           }
       }

       function evaluate(){
           var evaluatedOutput = eval(buttonVal);
           document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = evaluatedOutput;
       }
       operatorEl[6].onclick = evaluate;
</script>
```

That's all my JS code. When I check the debugger there are no errors, but none of the buttons work or display the input they're supposed to. I believe all of the logic makes total sense.

Anyway, any and all help would be appreciated. I'm guessing I messed up putting my buttons in the array incorrectly or something to that effect. It could also be something with .textContent or .innerHTML those are still a bit confusing to me and I mix them up occasionally.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is the HTML content as someone requested it:

```
        <body >
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id='h1'>Online Calculator</h1>
    <div class='col-md-6' id='calc-box'>
      <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">
                <input id="display" type="text" class="form-control display" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="button11" type="button" value="CE" class="btn operator" /></td>
            <td><input id="button12" type="button" value="Back" class="btn operator" /></td>
            <td><input id="button13" type="button" value="(" class="btn addme" /></td>
            <td><input id="button14" type="button" value=")" class="btn addme" /></td>
            <td><input id="button15" type="button" value="+" class="btn addme" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="button21" type="button" value="COS" class="btn operator" /></td>
            <td><input id="button22" type="button" value="7" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button23" type="button" value="8" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button24" type="button" value="9" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button25" type="button" value="-" class="btn addme" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="button31" type="button" value="SIN" class="btn operator" /></td>
            <td><input id="button32" type="button" value="4" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button33" type="button" value="5" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button34" type="button" value="6" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button35" type="button" value="*" class="btn addme" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="button41" type="button" value="SQRT" class="btn operator" /></td>
            <td><input id="button42" type="button" value="1" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button43" type="button" value="2" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button44" type="button" value="3" class="btn addme"  /></td>
            <td><input id="button45" type="button" value="/" class="btn addme" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="button51" type="button" value="log" class="btn operator" /></td>
            <td><input id="button52" type="button" value="0" class="btn addme"    /></td>
            <td><input id="button53" type="button" value="." class="btn addme" /></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input id="button54" type="button" value="=" class="btn operator" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div id='error-msg'></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided the HTML for your controls. However, you have an if statement instead of defining a function for the onclick of the 'addme' classed buttons.

Your code should read:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++) {
  btnElements[i].onclick = function() {
    buttonVal += this.value;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = buttonVal;
  }
}
```

With the rest of the code I can see the other issues. So:

As you are using an `<input>` for display, use the `value` property on all setting and retrieving of the data for it.

The Back button code you have (as mentioned by @Thanasis Grammatopoulo) returns a value but you have not stored it for use. Also, you have not reduced the size of the string - it is the same as when retrieved. So I have corrected that also.

Rather than using getElementById over and over, I have put the elements into a variable accessible to the functions.

That should fix the functionality issues...

```js
      < script type = "text/javascript" >
       // Addings operators
       var operatorEl = document.getElementsByClassName('operator');
      // Adding btnElements
     var btnElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addme');
      //var to store user input and button input
     var inputVal = '';
     var buttonVal = '';
     var display = document.getElementById('display');
     var errorMsg = document.getElementById('error-msg');

     function clearContent() {
       display.value = '';
       buttonVal = '';
       inputVal = '';
     }
     operatorEl[0].onclick = clearContent;

     function backBtn() {
       var dvLength = buttonVal.length;
       var reducedInput = buttonVal.substring(0, dvLength - 1);
       display.value = reducedInput;
     }
     operatorEl[1].onclick = backBtn;

     function calcCos() {
       inputVal = display.value;
       var newVal = Math.cos(inputVal);
       display.value = newVal;
     }
     operatorEl[2].onclick = calcCos;

     function calcSin() {
       inputVal = display.value;
       var newVal = Math.sin(inputVal);
       display.value = newVal;
     }
     operatorEl[3].onclick = calcSin;

     function calcSqrt() {
       inputVal = display.value;
       if (inputVal < 0) {
         errorMsg.innerHTML = 'Cannot calculate the square root of a negative number.';
         display.value = '';
       }

       var newVal = Math.sqrt(inputVal);
       display.value = newVal;
     }
     operatorEl[4].onclick = calcSqrt;

     function calcLog() {
       inputVal = display.value;
       if (inputVal < 1) {
         errorMsg.innerHTML = 'Cannot calculate the log of a non-positive number.';
         display.value = '';
       }

       var newVal = Math.log(inputVal);
       display.value = newVal;
     }
     operatorEl[5].onclick = calcLog;

      //When clicked the button's value will be added to the buttonVal and put into display
     for (var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++) {
       btnElements[i].onclick = function() {
         buttonVal += this.value;
         display.value = buttonVal;
       }
     }

     function evaluate() {
       var evaluatedOutput = eval(buttonVal);
       display.value = evaluatedOutput;
     }
     operatorEl[6].onclick = evaluate; < /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id='h1'>Online Calculator</h1>
    <div class='col-md-6' id='calc-box'>
      <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" colspan="5">
            <input id="display" type="text" class="form-control display" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="button11" type="button" value="CE" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button12" type="button" value="Back" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button13" type="button" value="(" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button14" type="button" value=")" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button15" type="button" value="+" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="button21" type="button" value="COS" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button22" type="button" value="7" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button23" type="button" value="8" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button24" type="button" value="9" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button25" type="button" value="-" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="button31" type="button" value="SIN" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button32" type="button" value="4" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button33" type="button" value="5" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button34" type="button" value="6" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button35" type="button" value="*" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="button41" type="button" value="SQRT" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button42" type="button" value="1" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button43" type="button" value="2" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button44" type="button" value="3" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button45" type="button" value="/" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="button51" type="button" value="log" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button52" type="button" value="0" class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="button53" type="button" value="." class="btn addme" />
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input id="button54" type="button" value="=" class="btn operator" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div id='error-msg'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I've changed my code now to  have `btnElements[i].onclick = function() {` followed by the rest of the code. My buttons still are not working though.

Comment: Can you put your HTML up to please?

Comment: You're a lifesaver! It works now. Figuring out when to use `.value`, `.innerHTML`, and `.textContent` really confuse me sometimes. Same with `.getElementById` I did notice with the Back button. When I use it then input another value, the value I previously got rid of shows up along with the new value I've inputted. What would cause that? Everytime I press back if calls the function all over again so I'm confused how that value is still sticking around.

Comment: Sorry, my miss, change the backBtn code to:
var dvLength = buttonVal.length;
buttonVal = buttonVal.substring(0, dvLength - 1);
display.value = buttonVal;

Comment: innerHTML is what goes between the two tags, an <input> element doesn't have a close tag so get its value instead. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

- Clear Button

  You need to clear your variables too, not only the screen.

  `inputVal = '';`
  `buttonVal = '';`
- Back Button
  Substring returns the new string, so you have to save it.
  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp
- Fix your way you get and set element's values

  You use :

  - `document.getElementById('display').value`
  - `document.getElementById('display').innerHTML`
  - `document.getElementById('display').textContent`

  you may want to use one way only because you may get different values.
- Fix your calculator's errors check

  After you check for example if the number under the sqr is positive return, do not continue to execute the code.

Your onclick events on button elements is wrong

```
//When clicked the button's value will be added to the buttonVal and put into display
for(var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++){
    if(btnElements[i].onclick){
        buttonVal += btnElements[i].value;
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = buttonVal;
    }
}
```

has to become something like ...

```
//When clicked the button's value will be added to the buttonVal and put into display
// For each button
for(var i = 0; i < btnElements.length; i++){
    // Bind event on element
    btnElements[i].onclick = function(){
        // varible 'this' holds the element
        buttonVal += this.value;
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = buttonVal;
    };
}
```

Comment: Grammatopoulo I really appreciate all your help and the thorough response. I made the changes to my code. And for my Log and Sqrt functions I put a `return false` at the end of my if statement so the code will not continue to execute. Also I stored my substring result in another variable and then transfered that variable back to buttonVal like this: `var newButtonVal = buttonVal.substring(0, dvLength);` followed by, `buttonVal = newButtonVal;` After that I changed my onclick event function to match yours. None of my buttons are working yet though.